# Adding several attachments to thunderbird (from command line)

Tags: user-interface, command-line, thunderbird, xdgutils

I try to create a new message with several attachments via command line, but this does not work:

```
thunderbird -compose "attachment='/etc/mtab',attachment='/etc/fstab'"
```

Only the first file gets attached. The second is missing.

What is wrong with the above command line?

PS: I tried xdg-email first, but this fails. See [How to open the user's preferred mail application on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236963/how-to-open-the-users-preferred-mail-application-on-linux)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the command must be specified as

```
thunderbird -compose "attachment='/etc/mtab,/etc/fstab'"
```

I have tried under windows.

Comment: I tried it under linux, it works too. Note however that the attachment must be written with its absolute path.

Comment: Note that if you call this from python, you have to replace the comma by %2C


`import os
command = f'thunderbird -compose to="{receiver}",subject="{subject}",body="{body_text}",attachment="{file_path1}%2C{file_path2}"'
os.system(command)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to attach several files:

```
thunderbird.exe -compose to="info@gmail.com" ,subject="SubjectText" ,body="bodytext" ,attachment='D:\File.txt,D:\File2.txt'
```

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer that has been on the site for well over a year?

Comment: Thank you. This answer was helpful to understand how to set the To and Subject fields.